# jQuery sub menu not opening in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following piece of jquery which slides open the sub menus when the parent item is clicked. It works fine on chrome but on firefox the sub menus dont open. Any ideas ?

```
(function($) {
"use strict";

  $( '.menu-area ul li' ).on('click', function() {

if($(this).closest("li").children("ul").length) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(300);
}
else{
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.screen-washer').removeClass("right");
  //$('.screen-washer').addClass("left");

  //console.log($('a').attr('href'));
  var linkLocation = $(this).children('a:first').attr('href');
        //alert(linkLocation);
        if (linkLocation.indexOf('#') >= 0) {} else {
            setTimeout(function() {
                //$('.preloader').fadeIn(300);
                window.location = linkLocation;
            }, 500);
        }

}
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hi @Scott, can you share your HTML too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Event handler - function() - "event" is missing, so Mozilla stops with an error when it reaches the non-available variable on parsing.

Should be:

```
$('.menu-area ul li').on('click', function(event) {...}
```

Comment: More specifically, it's perfectly legal to use just `function()`, but you are referring to `event` in the function (`event. preventDefault()`) so you'll need to include it.

Comment: Yes, Mozilla writes ReferenceError when encounters preventDefault, while Chrome says nothing.

Comment: Yup, Chrome "helpfully" pre-defines the variable _event_ for you.  If it had been called something else, say `ev` or `e`, it would fail in Chrome too.

Comment: perfect!! Thank you :)